# Why I can't update my database when saving data from 10 radioButtons?

Tags: java, database, indexing

I have 10 toggleGroup Buttons with 4 radio buttons each. When you click one radio button within a toggle group, It will add the index value of the selected radio button to an Arraylist. THen I have a "save" button to save those values to a database.

```
    public ArrayList<Integer> RightInt(){
                    for(ToggleGroup tg: toggleRDB()) {
                    tg.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->{
                        if(newValue != null) {

    //adds the index of the selected RadioButton to selectedRDBIndex list
     selectedRDBIndex.add(tg.getToggles().indexOf(newValue));
                        }
                    });
                            }

                        return selectedRDBIndex;
                        }

    //selectedRDBIndex is an ArrayList<Integer> storage.
```

The code above returns a list of Integer with 10 values.

This code is the action performed by the save button.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  //answerStore.storeRDB connects to my dataBase to save the values returned by the RightInt() function.
        answerStore.storeRDB(i+1, TB, RightInt().get(i));
        }
         RightInt().clear();
```

The code above works well. It saves and updates values to my database.

Then I decided to use those values again here:

```
for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++) {
                    toggleRDB().get(i).getToggles().get(answerStoration.retrieveDataRDBSet(i+1,TB)).setSelected(true);              
                }
//toggleRDB() returns a list of toggleGroups.
//answerStoration.retrieveDataRDBSet gets the radioButton integer data in the database that i used to setSelect an index of radioButton in each toggle group.
```

I used all these codes so that when the user selected a radioButton that progress will be saved. But after using the code above I can't update datas in my database. I hope you understood my situation and solve this problem. THanks in advance.

I got some hints on my problem. When I click a radio button 
It adds another place on the arraylist that's why the values aren't changing. Now I need figure out where to place a set () method or how to replace those values. I would like to say that clearing the list is not an option.